# Python Bottle upload file without form

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to save files sent from C++ code(not by HTML)
But I do not know how to write the script to parse sent data and save it
C++ code works fine(from wireshark captured packet)

from Bottle tutorial: how do I edit it?
    `category = request.forms.get('category')`
    `upload = request.files.get('upload')`
thanks!

update:
I found that `request.files` works

```
files = request.files
for name, fobj in files.iteritems():
    fobj.save(some_path)
```

Comment: It would be useful to see enough of your C++ code to know how you're using HTTP to send it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just sending the raw file in the HTTP request, access it with `request.body`.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.body

Comment: Thanks,now I can access the data by `request.body.getvalue()` or `request.body,read()`, but `request.body` seems a stringIO instance, I have to implement save() myself?

Comment: Nice find on the request.files.iteritems, because you are correct that otherwise it would require a custom save function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
from bottle import FileUpload

uploaded_file = FileUpload(request.body, None, filename='some_filename')
uploaded_file.save() # implement conflict resolution here, if needed
```